# Installing MySQL-Python on Mac OSX 10.6 64-bit Intel (Snow Leopard)

Tags: python, mysql, osx-snow-leopard

Been trying to install MySQL-Python with no luck. There are plenty of guides out there, but many appear incomplete and come with their own slew of errors.

I can't find any good formal documentation on what operating systems are supported by each version of MySQL-Python. At the moment, I'm trying to install version 1.2.3 on a 64-bit Mac running OSX 10.6.

The latest error I've received:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Aug  2 2010, 20:10:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/justianmeyer/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/justianmeyer/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Running `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/` after the installation, as suggested online, did nothing.

Although it shouldn't matter at this point in the install, MySQL has been configured successfully and is currently running on my system.

Is there any clear tutorial for this specific type of installation or guide to resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**

Similar issue when installing psycopg2 to work with PostgreSQL:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Aug  2 2010, 20:10:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

From the looks of this, it looks like I am missing dependencies.  What could they be?  what am I missing?

Comment: I had similar problems with mysql and 10.6. I gave up and switched to postgres after making a significant effort.  YMMV.

Comment: joel3000: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been messing around with many different db programs besides MySQL. Postgres was probably my second server that I attempted to connect my script to. It seems like, no matter which driver I use, I get these types of errors. It's likely that I'm missing a step in the installations.

Comment: Consider using [macports](http://www.macports.org/), there is a special port for that (py26-mysql @1.2.3). For me, macports is a preferred method for installing and updating open-source software.

Comment: @Dmitry M: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm coming back with `Unrecognized action "py26-mysql"` after running `sudo port py26-mysql`. I see it exists on the macports site here: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/python/py26-mysql/Portfile, but no luck.

Comment: Sure you need to run `sudo port install py26-mysql` :)

Comment: @Dmitry M: -facepalm- Will get on that tomorrow. Thanks for being kind about it. :P

Comment: @Dmitry M: No luck. I receive the same error as above when importing.